# Display private JS props in "Structure" panel of IDEA (PhpStorm)

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, ide, code-structure

This is my sample JavaScript code with private/public properties/methods:

```
"use strict";

function ClassName() {
    const PRIVATE_CONST = "private constant";
    const privateMap = new Map();
    const privateObj = {};
    this.publicProp = "";

    this.publicMethod = function () {
    };

    function privateMethod() {

    }
}

module.exports = ClassName;
```

I can see all public properties of the `ClassName` object in "Structure" panel but I cannot see some private properties there:
[image]

So, I see `privateObj`, but I cannot see `PRIVATE_CONST` & `privateMap`.

Does any configuration options exist in IDEA to display all properties or this is a bug?

Comment: By design, local variables are not shown in Structure view and it's hard to distinguish them from private constants. Please feel free to comment and vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9751.

Comment: Thanks, Oksana, I've voted for WEB-9751. This issue was created 6 years ago and I'm a 3rd voter for the feature at this moment :(